# Python - how do calculate the time difference between local and server

Tags: php, python, zend-framework, datetime, time

In the same time my local time and server time is not equal, for example:

1) My PC local time is

```
$ python -c 'import time;print (time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %I:%M-%S"))'
2013-11-12 12:35:44
```

2) From server i am getting JSON:

```
  public function waitingAction() {
    $sql = "select status,createdate from sh_av_queue where `status`='waiting'";
    $result = $this->db->fetchAll($sql);
    $content = Zend_Json::encode($result);
    $this->getResponse()
            ->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
            ->setBody($content)
            ->sendResponse();
    exit;
  }  

[{"status":"waiting","createdate":"2013-11-12 15:35:44"}]
```

3) Now in local PC, i have to represent a time differences in such format:

`00:00:00`
`00:00:01`
...
`00:00:59`

How do i make the time comparison correct in such situation? 
(cause my time is different in local from the server time but at the same time two different time i have to compare as it was in local PC time compare)

Comment: Try with [`diff`](http://br.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find the difference between server local time and your PC local time:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import json
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime

local_dt = datetime.now()
data = json.load(urllib2.urlopen(server_url))
# -> [{"status":"waiting","createdate":"2013-11-12 15:35:44"}]
server_dt = datetime.strptime(data[0]["createdate"], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
# -> datetime(2013, 11, 12, 15, 35, 44)
print(server_dt - local_dt)
# -> 3:00:00
```

You can construct the string manually:

```
td = server_dt - local_dt
minutes, seconds = divmod(td.total_seconds(), 60)
hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
print("%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hours, minutes, seconds))
#-> 03:00:00
```

To compare clocks, you should probably use UTC time on both the server and the PC:

```
utc_dt = datetime.utcnow() # PC
```